# Python: Finding length of the repeating sequence of numbers in a string of floats

Tags: python, regex, repeat

I am trying to write a function which takes in a list of floats and determines whether or not there is a repeating sequence of number within that list. If there is a repeating sequence then it counts the numbers in that sequence.

These examples are what I want my function to do

Example 1:

```
function = '1.0 8.0 4.0 2.0 1.0 8.0 4.0 2.0 1.0 8.0 4.0 2.0 1.0 8.0'
result = find_repeating_sequence(function)
# repeating sequence = 1.0, 8.0, 4.0, 2.0
# so result should equal 4 in this case
```

Example 2:

```
function = '1.0 8.0 4.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 8.0 4.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 8.0'
result = find_repeating_sequence(function)
# repeating sequence = 1.0, 8.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0
# so result should equal 5 in this case
```

Example 3:

```
function = '1.0 8.0 4.0 2.0 1.0 7.0 6.0 3.0 2.0 5.0 9.0'
result = find_repeating_sequence(function)
# repeating sequence doesn't exist
# so result should equal None in this case
```

Example 4:

```
function = '1.0 11.0 1.0 11.0 1.0 11.0 1.0 11.0 1.0 11.0 1.0 11.0 1.0 11.0 1.0 11.0'
result = find_repeating_sequence(function)
# repeating sequence = 1.0, 11.0
# so result should equal 2 in this case
```

So far what I have got is:

```
def find_repeating_sequence(function):
        regex = re.compile(r'(.+ .+)( \1)+')
        match = regex.search(function)
        result = match

       if result == None:
            print "There was no repeating sequence found!"
        else:
            print "Repeating sequence found!"
            print match.group(1)
            result = match.group(1)

       return result
```

This works for all examples in the sense that `match.group(1)` gives the repeating sequence. However for some reason `len(match.group(1))` does not return the correct number.

Like for Example 1:

`print match.group(1)` gives `1.0 8.0 4.0 2.0`

But `print len(match.group(1))` gives `15`

Also it does not return the correct value for Example 4:
`print match.group(1)` gives `1.0 11.0 1.0 11.0 1.0 11.0 1.0 11.0`

And `print len(match.group(1))` gives `35`

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to one of the answers below I have solved the `print len(match.group(1))` issue by using len(match.group(1).split())

However for some reason if
`function = 1.0 2.0 4.0 8.0 1.0 2.0 4.0 8.0 1.0 2.0 4.0 8.0 1.0 2.0 4.0 8.0`
`print match.group(1)` gives `1.0 2.0 4.0 8.0 1.0 2.0 4.0 8.0`
and not `1.0 2.0 4.0 8.0`

Comment: 1.0 8.0 4.0 2.0 1.0 8.0 4.0 2.0 is not contained in your search string, did you mixed the numbers?

Comment: @radicarl Apologies, yes I copied the wrong number. I have now rectified that mistake in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

match.group() returns a string and in this case len() returns the number of characters in the string.

you could split your string by space, and then count the number of elements

Answer to the update:
your expression is greedy, it tries to find the longest match. Try `(.+? .+?)( \1)+?`. The questionmark after a qualifier makes the regex lazy:

https://regex101.com/r/1w7nxD/1